# Tooltip max-width with white-space: nowrap

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to overarchitect a tooltip. The goal is for the tooltip abstraction to not have any knowledge of the wide context (document). Instead, it should be placed in an element and just work.

However, I'm having difficulty achieving max-width behaviour:

[image]

Understandably so, since the content has `white-space: nowrap`.

However, without it, I face this problem:

[image]

Help me fix the layout so that I may get a proper max-width behaviour. Specifically, when there is no more room in the line, wrap the content in a new line.

Here's the example: https://jsbin.com/fucujak/3/edit?html,css,output

```css
helper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  left:30%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 300px
}

tooltip {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}

tooltip:hover tooltip-anchor {
  display: block;
}

tooltip-anchor {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
tooltip-container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
tooltip-positioner {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}
tooltip-content {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <helper>
    i
    <tooltip>
      <tooltip-anchor>
        <tooltip-container>
          <tooltip-positioner>
            <tooltip-content>
              Some long, extended tooltip content
            </tooltip-content>
          </tooltip-positioner>
        </tooltip-container>
      </tooltip-anchor>
    </tooltip>
  </helper>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: why all the complicated markup?

Comment: @Paulie_D done 

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you're able to replicate the illustrated behaviour without the complex markup, I'm very open to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do like below:

```css
helper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 300px
}

tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
  top: 100%; /* place at bottom*/
  /* center*/
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  /**/
  margin-right: -200px; /* this is the trick that will make sure the content can go up to 180px (an arbitrary big value) */
  max-width:180px; /* your max-width*/
  padding:10px;
  background:blue;
}
helper:hover tooltip {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<helper>
  i
  <tooltip>
    Some long, extended tooltip content
  </tooltip>
</helper>

<helper>
  i
  <tooltip>
    Some long
  </tooltip>
</helper>
```

Comment: The reason I wasn't able to utilize transform is because i need it in pristine state for some complex transitions. But holy cow that margin-right caught me off guard. It works in my example too! You don't even need max-width in your example.

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski yes you can omit max-width if you set the exact value for margin-right but I wanted to highlight the fact that you simply need a big value there and you can use any max-width you want

Comment: My finding was that once you provide the negative margin, the max-width becomes unnecessary. Can you point me to some resource that helps understand all the relationships that are going on here, and how the negative margin fixes things?

Comment: For anyone wondering, [here's a variant](https://jsbin.com/fucujak/6/edit?html,css,output) with both margin-right and max-width, but also, [here's a variant](https://jsbin.com/fucujak/7/edit?html,css,output) with only margin-right.

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski the logic is based on the equation here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width

Comment: That equation talks about the positioning of the element, and, unfortunately I'm unable to relate it to the width magic introduced by negative margin that allows for width beyond of the parent width.

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski that equation talks about the width of an absolute positionned element (not its position). Margin-right is part of that equation which allow me to control the final width